# How to get all triggering environments from SQL Server database

Tags: sql, sql-server, bamboo

I am trying to query bamboo's database to get the following information.  I want to find out the **trigger information**, which is what environment is triggered by which branch on which build plan. The problem is that some **environments** can be triggered by other **environments**.

So far I have looked up the Bamboo database and I seem to have most if not all the information that I need.  What I have done is there is a table in the Bamboo database called **dbo.Deployment_Environment** which has the fields, **EnvironmentID** and **Triggers_XML_Data** which is exactly what I need from it.  Then there is another table called the dbo.**Deployment_Result** which has the **EnvironmentID**, **Deployment_State** and the **Trigger_Reason**.

From these two tables what I think I need to do is this.  select all these columns but if the **trigger_reason** contains **environment** and also if the **triggers_xml_data** contains **environment**, then get that **environment** from the **triggers_xml_Data** (this is under the xml node **/item/value**).  Once you get that ID select all the same columns until and repeat the process if environment is the reason for deployment again until it is not.  The **triggers_xml_data** data type is **ntext** and the **trigger_reason** is **nvarchar**.

I am not exactly sure how I can do this in SQL this is what I am trying so far but I can't get the right information:

```
alter proc dbo.myStoredProc3
as
    Declare @EnvironmentID int

    select 
        @EnvironmentID as ENVIRONMENT_ID, 
        de.ENVIRONMENT_ID, dr.DEPLOYMENT_STATE, 
        de.TRIGGERS_XML_DATA, dr.TRIGGER_REASON, de.NAME
    from 
        dbo.BUILDRESULTSUMMARY as br, 
        dbo.DEPLOYMENT_ENVIRONMENT as de, 
        dbo.DEPLOYMENT_RESULT as dr
    where 
        dr.TRIGGER_REASON like '%environment%' 
(
    select de2.ENVIRONMENT_ID as 'test'     
    from dbo.DEPLOYMENT_ENVIRONMENT as de2
)
```

I know this is not going to get the right information but every time I tried to do case's or if statements in the SQL it would create an error too:  How can I do this query correctly?  I think that I all the information I need but if not I can add more.

I have also tried to do the following:

```
While (@Counter <= 5)
Begin
Select de.NAME As 'Deployment Name', dr.TRIGGER_REASON as 'Trigger Reason', dr.DEPLOYMENT_STATE as 'Status'
from dbo.DEPLOYMENT_ENVIRONMENT as de, dbo.DEPLOYMENT_RESULT as dr
Where de.TRIGGERS_XML_DATA like '%environment%' and dr.TRIGGER_REASON like '%environment%'
SET @Counter = @Counter + 1
END
```

But this will not link the columns that I am getting. If the **Trigger_Reason** is to do with the **environment** then in the **ntext** the it will have a **node** that has the **environmentID**, I want to get this and **set** it as a **variable**, which I can use to get further columns that link to together e.g. *`Select name from dbo.Environment where @NewEnvironmentID = de.EnvironmentID.`*

**Edit**

Using the following SQL query:

```
alter proc getEnvironmentTriggers
@EnvironmentID int
as
Select a.NAME, a.TRIGGERS_XML_DATA, a.TRIGGER_REASON, a.ENVIRONMENT_ID
From (Select de.NAME, de.TRIGGERS_XML_DATA, de.ENVIRONMENT_ID, dr.TRIGGER_REASON From dbo.DEPLOYMENT_ENVIRONMENT as de
Inner join dbo.DEPLOYMENT_RESULT as dr 
on dr.ENVIRONMENT_ID = de.ENVIRONMENT_ID
Where @EnvironmentID = de.ENVIRONMENT_ID and de.TRIGGERS_XML_DATA like '%Environment%' and dr.TRIGGER_REASON like '%Environment%' ) a
```

I am getting close to what I need.  Doing this and the executing the Stored procedure like this: `exec dbo.getEnvironmentTriggers 15892483`, this will return in the query inside the ntext l of the **TRIGGERS_XML_DATA**, will have a value of 18317322, and then using that ID I can get the value of 19234819, that is then the last environment that triggers all of my environments from that ID.

So what I am trying to do is this:

1. In an automated way get all of these ID's possibly by doing the following.
2. Exec the stored procedure using all of the ID's (maybe using some sort of for each way).
3. Search the `ntext` column in the SQL to get the environment ID (this is in the following node **/item/value**.
4. Store that as a variable, then use it to get all the columns from the other stored procedure.
5. If there is returned columns using the stored procedure, run the procedure again, if not export all of the TRIGGER_XML_DATA columns that were got from stored procedures.

Is there a way that I can do this?

Comment: It's not clean what you want to achieve. 


deployment_environment table contains environment definition. Here you can see what triggers and tasks used for this environment


deployment_result table contains historical information about deployment of releases. So what release was deployed to which environment.


Can you please describe what should be result of your query/investigation

Comment: I get all the environments that are dependent on each other so basically if environment id-1, runs then it will make 2, 3, 4, run and then 3 will make 5 and 6 run.  These are all dependent on each other but they are all columns in the table so if possible I would like to query the table so that I select their names if the id's match from the previous environment which is in the trigger_xml_data field. The result would be 1 --> (2, 3 -->(5,6) ,4).

Answer (score 1):

See my answer here - https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/44908050/how-to-get-the-trigger-information-from-the-bamboo-database

Not sure it's possible to do with plain SQL

Comment: That is right but I am having trouble getting it using SQL which is what my problem is.

Answer (score 1):

What about using [Bamboo REST API](https://docs.atlassian.com/bamboo/REST/5.13.2/)

```
http://bamboo_host/rest/api/latest/plan.json?expand=plans.plan.actions
```